How would humans actually colonize Mars?
We've heard several times about how Elon Musk plans to take us to Mars using the Starship spacecraft. Although I do believe that given the time and money this is possible, I don't understand how we shall colonize/live on the planet. Will we live using oxygen obtained from earth or do we have plans for a natural ecosystem? How efficient would such a mission be?

Supplementry to the current answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_mission_to_Mars, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_Mars and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_One

Depends on whose plans you’re looking at

A search of multiple dictionaries yielded  varying definitions of "colony" and "colonization". For instance, many definitions centered on "subjugation of indigenous people", which is easily accomplished on Mars.  Since the word is central to the meaning of the question, clarification would be helpful.

@Woody I guess that depends on whether you use an all or exists quantor. ("Subjugate all indigenous people" = easy, there are none. "Subjugate some indigenous people" = impossible, there are none.)

I think the point is: Once you can go there, why would you want to go there, i.e.: What would you do there? Answering these question will probably be the answer to your question as well.

what @ScienceSnake said, although note it's a 2023 book not 2003

Re, "...oxygen obtained from earth..." Sounds like, when you say "oxygen," you mean O2. If so, then you're thinking at the wrong scale. There's plenty of oxygen atoms on Mars. A viable Mars colony would make its own O2 from available materials, using whatever source of power they use. What's really scarce on Mars is hydrogen, which is every bit as essential to organic chemistry and life as are oxygen and carbon and nitrogen, etc.

Robots are getting smarter and more physically capable faster than space colony technology is developing. That takes most of the wind out the sails for sending humans.

what does the "how efficient" portion of the question mean?

There are currently no serious plans for colonizing Mars
Any credible attempt at colonizing Mars is still a very, very, long way off. Right now, it's essentially just science fiction. Therefore, the question asked in "I don't understand how we shall colonize/live on the planet" is unanswerable, because right now, we won't, because there is no plan to actually do it.
If you are referring to Musk's "plan" specifically, then this question is also unanswerable, because beyond developing Starship and potentially some ISRU machinery for producing fuel at Mars, Musk's plan for colonization does not go beyond pretty CGI animations of glass domes on the Martian surface.

This might be nitpicking, but "it's essentially just science fiction" is exaggeration, especially given the follow-on questions asked by OP.  Actual engineering effort is being expended on Mars ISRU development, though I admit that the work has stayed very basic without sufficient development or budget and the best-known plans like Mars One are somewhere between fanciful and outright cons.

@ErinAnne I think I just set the bar to what I consider "colonization" to be rather high. For example, despite thousands of people currently living and working in Antarctica, I would not really consider the continent "colonized" in any way. Same with Mars, there will be quite a bit of manned exploration that needs to happen before a colonization effort can be attempted. Yes, some groups are working on technologies which, one day, could be used by Mars colonists but we haven't even sent a manned mission there, so anything we have now is, at best, a distant precursor to what will be used one day

@Dragongeek ... I like the comparison with the Antarctic. Despite being much more accessible and benign than mars, we do not have the technology to make the Antarctic independent of scheduled outside support. Like the ISS.

@Woody And yet if you asked for volunteers for a colony, I bet you'd get a lot more volunteers for Mars than for Antarctica...

@PM2Ring: That is because the average person has a heavily romanticized idea of what Mars would be like. You'd be living in a tiny box with no (or at best extremely limited) internet, no entertainment devices that weigh more than a pound or so, the outside world is miles and miles of brown, and you (probably) aren't allowed to do an EVA anyway unless you have a good reason. I'm sure there are people who would be willing to put up with all of that because it's Mars, but I tend to imagine that the novelty would wear off real quick for the average person.

@Kevin no entertainment devices that weigh more than a pound or so, - 20 years ago that would have been a problem. Now with modern tablets that's trivial. And shared large storage could provide decades worth of books, movies, etc. But food will be a biggie - until you have a huge nearly-self-sustaining "colony", all but the basics will be shipped from Earth - which means either very basic very boring limited menu or incredibly expensive - coffee, chocolate, beef? (actually beef might have the best chance with lab-grown meat) will all be Earth-sourced for a long time.

@Woody: I'm not necessarily certain that we don't have the technology to make the Antarctic independent so much as we've internationally agreed not to try to do it.. Mars arguably would run into the same roadblocks, even if someone did want to colonize Mars - namely, that someone else would also want to.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: I had been assuming we've already taken care of boring logistics, but yes, you'd pretty much have to have to go vegan because animal husbandry on Mars is laughably impractical. Plus all the specialty stuff is getting replaced with freeze-dried equivalents at best.

@Kevin Nearly every space-based sci-fi book I read has coffee and chocolate. A few discuss the limitations, but most gloss over the problems of growing and processing coffee - it isn't like wheat or beans or lettuce where you can throw some seeds in some soil and water and get something reasonable in a few months and the processing is much more complex - anyone could turn wheat into bread with minimal equipment, coffee and chocolate not so easy. But life without coffee and chocolate? Ugh!

@AlexanderThe1st Hmmm... "independent" is a strong word. Maybe we can reduce the supply runs from civilization to a Mars-doable twice a year or so...

Musk sometimes drops hints one time in an interview that give some insight into his thinking, sometimes never again to be repeated. For example a few years ago in an interview he explained "Elon time". He said it's how long it would take if everything went perfect. In the next sentence he said things rarely if ever go perfect. The real nugget was when he said that people get excited if you tell them something is 1-2 years away, much less excited if you say it's 5-10 years away. As for Mars, one interview I know of he said they are building the railroad, he expects others will build the colony

@Woody I don't think that's a good definition of colonization. Look at Hong Kong and Singapore, they wouldn't survive a day without energy, food, and water being shipped in. Even the island of Japan can only produce 40% of its food and 5% of its primary energy, the rest is imported. These (quasi-)countries can afford to ship, so if transport becomes economical to the Antarctic or Mars, then colonization can occur.

@user71659 If I had to come up with a modern definition for "colonized", I'd probably focus on the human life cycle. Is this a place where humans are regularly born, grow up, and die? Does it have pre-schools, funeral homes, etc? Many places that aren't self-sufficient still have these characteristics

@ErinAnne I'd strongly recommend reading "A City on Mars" by the Weinersmiths.  The fairest summary might be that we know it's science fiction because there's been enough effort put into figuring out how far we are away from knowing whether any of it could even work, never mind any of the details.  (Amazon link if you're interested: https://www.amazon.co.uk/City-Mars-Settle-Thought-Through/dp/1984881728)

To add onto Dragongeek's excellent answer, IF we were going to send a manned mission there with intentions of setting up a serious, self sufficient colony, we would almost certainly need a pretty substantial fission reactor.
A number of factors will limit the size that such a reactor could be and it will be operationally limited by the lack of free, flowing water on Mars for cooling and generation.
The power output of your primary reactor would be the main limiting factor to things like:

How much oxygen can you pull off of CO2 in the atmosphere (or other sources like oxides in the rocks)
How much water can you produce, purify, and recycle?
How large of a volume can you keep heated to human habitable (and agriculturally viable) temperatures?
How much infrastructure development can you power? (Digging, crushing, compacting, melting, electrolysing, etc)
How many rovers / bots can you power?
How much redundancy can you power in all of those systems?

Mars is insanely hostile. Keeping people alive requires immense amounts of resources that we mostly get for "free" here on Earth.
Most development will need to be done by rovers on the surface while humans are safely buried in habitats quite similar to the ISS.
Self sufficiency and population growth will very much depend on "Can we fabricate more power generation and storage before we exhaust our current supply and spare parts?".
"Can we keep a self sustaining biosphere alive?" is the next limiting factor. Experiments in isolated environments to date have NOT been promising.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2#Challenges)
Any serious proposal has an initial run of missions to deliver supplies and begin robotically constructing a habitat well before any humans ever get there.
It will need to continue to receive resupply missions for a LONG time after the first humans land as well.

Large amount of oxygen are not needed (except for use in rocket fuel)   it's really hard to grow food without also producing oxygen.

Even given the lower amount of sunlight reaching Mars's surface, solar power generation should be possible at scale, would provide more redundancy and be possibly more sustainable, depending on the life time of the panels. Is the environment with sandstorms etc. too harsh? Is the mass needed for comparable capacity higher than for a fission reactor?

Solar will be heavily utilized in any actual martian colony, yes. But it also is intermittent and you'd need batteries to balance load.
Dust is not really an issue anywhere that can do maintenance, we saw several rovers go for years without the ability to wipe their panels off.
If we assume 50% efficient solar panels, at a peak of ~600 watt / m^2 that mars receives, that's a max of 300w. Factoring in night time, let's call it 100w average.
There are modular nuclear fission plants in development that can do 1MW.  We'd need 10k m^2, or 0.01 km^2.

The ISS generates ~100KW, but has the luxury that space doesn't actually cool anything down quickly. Mars will.
Modern naval nuclear reactors can do at upwards of 50 MW and last for 30 years with no refueling.
The higher power and reliability is what will make the immense costs and weight usage worth it.
The heat produced by a fission reactor can be used to directly heat living quarters, electronic systems (during night), and for industrial applications without needing to convert it to electricity first.
Fabricating more solar panels in situ is the way to go.

@abestrange If we are serious about powering a Mars colony with solar power, then we probably will use space-based solar power instead of ground-based solar power. There are just so many more advantages to it, that it is probably the better way to go.
